# Check for errors in gtest using void functions

Tags: c++, googletest

When using helper functions in gtest which use the ASSERT_ or EXPECT_ macros then that helper function has to be void. However, I'd like to check for those errors within the calling test-code as well.

There is the ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE macro which helps to stop the calling code in case an ASSERT_ was triggered, but I'd like to extend that with proper handling of EXPECT_ failures (read: NonFatalFailures) as well. Here's what I got so far:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

// A void test-function using  ASSERT_ or EXPECT_ calls should be encapsulated by this macro.
// Example: CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(MyCheckForEquality(lhs, rhs))
#define CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(statement)                                                              \
  ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE((statement));                                                            \
  EXPECT_FALSE(HasNonfatalFailure())

void TestHelperFunction(bool givenAssert, int givenExpect)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(givenAssert);  // note: this is line 11 in my code
    EXPECT_EQ(givenExpect, 0); // note: this is line 12 in my code
}

TEST(FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks, noChecks)
{
    // note: this is line 17 in my code
    TestHelperFunction(true, 0);
    TestHelperFunction(true, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        TestHelperFunction(true, i);
    }
    TestHelperFunction(false, 1);
    TestHelperFunction(true, 2);
}

TEST(FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks, withChecks)
{
    // note: this is line 30 in my code
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(true, 0)) << "\n All good - will NOT be seen! \n";
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(true, 1)) << "\n optional msg: First Expect failed \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(true, i)) << "\n optional msg: Expect failed for i=" << i << "\n";
    }
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(false, 1)) << "this message will NOT be seen due to the assert";
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(true, 2)) << "\n will not be seen because assert stops the test \n";
}

// This test creates the following output:

// Note: Google Test filter = *FailureInFunctionTest*
// [==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
// [----------] Global test environment set-up.
// [----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks
// [ RUN      ] FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks.noChecks
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:12: Failure
// Expected equality of these values:
//   givenExpect
//     Which is: 1
//   0
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:12: Failure
// Expected equality of these values:
//   givenExpect
//     Which is: 1
//   0
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:12: Failure
// Expected equality of these values:
//   givenExpect
//     Which is: 2
//   0
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:11: Failure
// Value of: givenAssert
//   Actual: false
// Expected: true
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:12: Failure
// Expected equality of these values:
//   givenExpect
//     Which is: 2
//   0
// [  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks.noChecks (0 ms)
// [----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks (0 ms total)
// 
// [----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks
// [ RUN      ] FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks.withChecks
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:12: Failure
// Expected equality of these values:
//   givenExpect
//     Which is: 1
//   0
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:32: Failure
// Value of: HasNonfatalFailure()
//   Actual: true
// Expected: false
// 
//  optional msg: First Expect failed 
// 
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:35: Failure
// Value of: HasNonfatalFailure()
//   Actual: true
// Expected: false
// 
//  optional msg: Expect failed for i=0
// 
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:12: Failure
// Expected equality of these values:
//   givenExpect
//     Which is: 1
//   0
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:35: Failure
// Value of: HasNonfatalFailure()
//   Actual: true
// Expected: false
// 
//  optional msg: Expect failed for i=1
// 
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:12: Failure
// Expected equality of these values:
//   givenExpect
//     Which is: 2
//   0
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:35: Failure
// Value of: HasNonfatalFailure()
//   Actual: true
// Expected: false
// 
//  optional msg: Expect failed for i=2
// 
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:11: Failure
// Value of: givenAssert
//   Actual: false
// Expected: true
// ./checked_test_failure.cpp:37: Failure
// Expected: (TestHelperFunction(false, 1)) doesn't generate new fatal failures in the current thread.
//   Actual: it does.
// [  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks.withChecks (1 ms)
// [----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks (1 ms total)
// 
// [----------] Global test environment tear-down
// [==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (1 ms total)
// [  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
// [  FAILED  ] 2 tests, listed below:
// [  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks.noChecks
// [  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks.withChecks
// 
//  2 FAILED TESTS
//
```

As you can see from the output: Using the new 'CHECK_FOR_FAILURES' macro improves the test-output: It tells you which line caused a failure and it prevents executing a test after an assert was hit.

However, using 'HasNonfatalFailure()' is not good enough as you can see in the output for i=0. The reason is there was a non-fatal error already and for i=0 there was no NEW non-fatal error but the HasNonfatalFailure() returns true due to the old one.. :-(

Any idea how I can get rid of the wrong i=0 output?

Comment: It looks to me that other tests still continue after an assert so I fail to see the use of this construction?

Comment: Hi @FrederikDeRuyck, not sure what you mean: in the output you can see for the first test that the assert didn't prevent the next line to be executed. But in the second test (with that macro encapsulation) it stops at the assert and you don't see "will not be seen because assert stops the test", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious way using the [suggestion of gtest docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#using-assertions-in-sub-routines) is the following, but I'd rather do it without custom messages or the SCOPED_TRACE() macro

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

// A void test-function using  ASSERT_ or EXPECT_ calls with a custom message should be encapsulated
// by this macro. Example: CHECK_FOR_FAILURES_MSG(MyCheckForEquality(counter, 42), "for counter=42")
#define CHECK_FOR_FAILURES_MSG(statement, message)                                                 \
{                                                                                                  \
    SCOPED_TRACE(message);                                                                         \
    ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE((statement));                                                          \
}

// A void test-function using  ASSERT_ or EXPECT_ calls should be encapsulated by this macro.
// Example: CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(MyCheckForEquality(lhs, rhs))
#define CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(statement) CHECK_FOR_FAILURES_MSG(statement, " <--  line of failure\n")

void TestHelperFunction(bool givenAssert, int givenExpect)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(givenAssert);  // note: this is line 17 in my code
    EXPECT_EQ(givenExpect, 0); // note: this is line 18 in my code
}

TEST(FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks, noChecks)
{
    // note: this is line 23 in my code
    TestHelperFunction(true, 0);
    TestHelperFunction(true, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        TestHelperFunction(true, i);
    }
    TestHelperFunction(false, 1);
    TestHelperFunction(true, 2);
}

TEST(FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks, withChecks)
{
    // note: this is line 36 in my code
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(true, 0));
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(true, 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        CHECK_FOR_FAILURES_MSG(TestHelperFunction(true, i), "for i=" + std::to_string(i) + "\n");
    }
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(false, 1));
    CHECK_FOR_FAILURES(TestHelperFunction(true, 2));
}

// Note: Google Test filter = *FailureInFunction*
//[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
//[----------] Global test environment set-up.
//[----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks
//[ RUN      ] FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks.noChecks
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:18: Failure
//Expected equality of these values:
//  givenExpect
//    Which is: 1
//  0
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:18: Failure
//Expected equality of these values:
//  givenExpect
//    Which is: 1
//  0
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:18: Failure
//Expected equality of these values:
//  givenExpect
//    Which is: 2
//  0
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:17: Failure
//Value of: givenAssert
//  Actual: false
//Expected: true
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:18: Failure
//Expected equality of these values:
//  givenExpect
//    Which is: 2
//  0
//[  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks.noChecks (0 ms)
//[----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks (0 ms total)
//
//[----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks
//[ RUN      ] FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks.withChecks
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:18: Failure
//Expected equality of these values:
//  givenExpect
//    Which is: 1
//  0
//Google Test trace:
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:38:  <--  line of failure
//
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:18: Failure
//Expected equality of these values:
//  givenExpect
//    Which is: 1
//  0
//Google Test trace:
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:41: for i=1
//
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:18: Failure
//Expected equality of these values:
//  givenExpect
//    Which is: 2
//  0
//Google Test trace:
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:41: for i=2
//
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:17: Failure
//Value of: givenAssert
//  Actual: false
//Expected: true
//Google Test trace:
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:43:  <--  line of failure
//
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:43: Failure
//Expected: (TestHelperFunction(false, 1)) doesn't generate new fatal failures in the current thread.
//  Actual: it does.
//Google Test trace:
//./checked_test_failure.cpp:43:  <--  line of failure
//
//[  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks.withChecks (0 ms)
//[----------] 1 test from FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks (0 ms total)
//
//[----------] Global test environment tear-down
//[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
//[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
//[  FAILED  ] 2 tests, listed below:
//[  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestNoChecks.noChecks
//[  FAILED  ] FailureInFunctionTestWithChecks.withChecks
//
// 2 FAILED TESTS
//
```